# Can a SystemVerilog function return a value of a type defined in a package?

Tags: system-verilog

Can a SystemVerilog function return a value of a type defined in a package?
How do I import the package before I declare the type of the function?

Comment: You need to show an example of the trouble you are having. You can define types in packages and either import before you reference them, or explicitly reference the package. There is nothing special about functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to return a datatype value, which was defined in a package.

Here is a sample code for it.

```
package tmp;
  typedef bit[1:0] x;
endpackage

import tmp::*;

module tp();
  x a;

  initial
  begin
    a = return_x();
    $display("a - %p", a);
  end
endmodule

function x return_x();
  return_x = 3;
endfunction

// Output 
// a = 3
```